# Release `resource` in a Luigi pipeline

Tags: python, pipeline, luigi

I have a Luigi pipeline which consists of a graph of tasks that I run in batch. Some of those tasks rely on a costly resource (for example AWS EC2 cluster of machines, or other costly resource).

I am trying to use this `resource` in a smart way, so that I `acquire` it prior to running the tasks and `release` it as soon as all tasks have completed. In general the costly resource is allocated in the beginning of the pipeline, and half-way through the dependency graph could very well be released.

Is there an efficient way to model this in Luigi, to achieve the `aquire` and `release` of the resource?

Modelling it in terms of `Aquire` and `Release` `luigi.Task`s is not optimal, because it adds a lot of complexity and unnecessary edges to my graph. Ideally the `scheduler` would check its `state` and when there are no more `RUNNING` or `PENDING` tasks that require the resource, it could `release` it.

Does this exist already, or I would have to add this functionality to Luigi myself?

Answer (score 1):

Luigi support the concepts of resources that will take it when the task is Scheduled and run, and then released when the taks is finished. Why do you need a more advanced approach.

From the [doc](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#resources):

> This section can contain arbitrary keys. Each of these specifies the amount of a global resource that the scheduler can allow workers to use. The scheduler will prevent running jobs with resources specified from exceeding the counts in this section. Unspecified resources are assumed to have limit 1. Example resources section for a configuration with 2 hive resources and 1 mysql resource:

```
[resources]
hive: 2
mysql: 1
```

In your case you can model this by having i.e.  `aws : 1`. This resource will then be used only once at the time. Now, if what you want is to control how the tasks are scheduled then you could try to use priorities.

Inside your task you can then add:

```
resources = {"aws": 1}
```

As far as I know there's no way to directly take resources as this is controlled by the task execution.

**UPDATED** (from the comment):

If for example you want to perform certain things (i.e. a cleanup) you might want to use  Event handlers for that.

```
 @luigi.Task.event_handler(luigi.Event.FAILURE)
 def handler_failure(self, exception):
       # do cleanups
```

See the full [documentation](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tasks.html?highlight=Events#events-and-callbacks) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @mfcabrera. I am already using this concept of Luigi resource in my pipeline. However this is useful only in terms of the scheduler not starting many tasks when a given resource is exhausted. Let's say EC2 can handle only 1 Luigi task at a time and you have 4 workers, then this is useful. However it has nothing to do with the actual acquire and release of the actual resource - say EC2. In your example, how would you implement starting and stopping of the actual AWS resource (say tasks StartCluster, and StopCluster) particularly in case of failures and disabled tasks?

Comment: Concretely in my current pipeline, StopCluster is the last task in the DAG. Therefore any failure and disabled upstream in the middle of the DAG causes the StopCluster to not be called, meaning I cannot release the EC2 instances in case of errors.

Comment: @AntonEvangelatov  have you tried event handlers? I will update the answer. Maybe that help.

Comment: not yet. It is not clear if this callback will be triggered after every Failure, or ultimately after the task fails the retry number of times. At the moment StopCluster is modeled as a wrapper of all those tasks that might fail. If I could dynamically update the dependecies of StopCluster (and remove the failing task if it fails 3 times, for example) that might solve it.